# boost::asio::io_context Socket Server + thread_group

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to make an https server based on sockets and distribute it into different streams. The server itself works fine, stably holds the load and processes requests if everything goes on the same thread. If I put it in different threads, then when testing under load (wrk), the server crashes... My code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>


#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

#include <iostream>






typedef boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ssl_socket;


class session
{
public:
    session(boost::asio::io_context& io_context,
        boost::asio::ssl::context& context)
        : socket_(io_context, context)
    {
    }

    ssl_socket::lowest_layer_type& socket()
    {
        return socket_.lowest_layer();
    }

    void start()
    {

        socket_.async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server,
            boost::bind(&session::handle_handshake, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
                boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    int req_rah = 0;

    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
        size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if (!error)
        {

        std::string  Result_test = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                std::string("Content-Length: 2\r\n") +
                std::string("Content-Type: text/html\r\n") +
                std::string("Connection: Closed\r\n\r\n") +
                std::string("ok") +
                std::string("\r\n");

            boost::asio::streambuf request_test;
            std::ostream request_stream_test(&request_test);

            request_stream_test << Result_test;

            boost::asio::write(socket_, request_test);

            boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                request_test,
                boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));




        }
        else
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
                boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

private:
    ssl_socket socket_;
    enum { max_length = 6291456 };
    char data_[max_length] = "";
};

class server
{
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, unsigned short port)
        : io_context_(io_context),
        acceptor_(io_context,
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port)),
        context_(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23)
    {
        context_.set_options(
            boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds
            | boost::asio::ssl::context::no_sslv2
            | boost::asio::ssl::context::single_dh_use);
        context_.set_password_callback(boost::bind(&server::get_password, this));
        context_.use_certificate_chain_file("Server.crt");
        context_.use_private_key_file("Server.key", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
        context_.use_tmp_dh_file("dh2048.pem");

        start_accept();
    }

    std::string get_password() const
    {
        return "";
    }

    void start_accept()
    {



        session* new_session = new session(io_context_, context_);
        acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
            boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_accept(session* new_session,
        const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            new_session->start();
        }
        else
        {
            delete new_session;
        }

        start_accept();
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_context& io_context_;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
    boost::asio::ssl::context context_;
};








int main(int argc,      
    char *argv[], 
    char *envp[])
{


    try
    {


        boost::asio::io_context io_context;
        boost::thread_group pool;



        server s(io_context, 8080);


        for (auto i = 0u; i<boost::thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i)
            pool.create_thread([&] {io_context.run(); });

        pool.join_all();


    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

when accessing from the browser https://127.0.0.1:8080 all the rules, I get "ok." When wrk is executed, everything crashes... As I understand, threads are being processed incorrectly (reading or/and answer), whoever faced a similar task, please help, what's wrong... Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have UB in `handle_read`. `request_test` is local, because you call `async_write` so function ends immediately, and `request_test` as local is destroyed as well. Why do you call as first `write` and later `async_write` with the same source buffer?

Comment: about "write and later async_write" it was my mistake when publishing code, sorry. about local  request_test I'm not understand, it's must be public?...

Comment: By local I mean kind of *storage* where variable is held. In functions variables are stored onto stack (named as local). You cannot pass reference to local variable to `async_write`, because inside asynchronous task initiated by `async_write` reference to this variable will dangle.

Answer (score 0):

I change send data to

```
boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                boost::asio::buffer(send_data.c_str(), send_data.size() + 1),
                boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

and now it works. But when I test it by wrk, I have the same result as when I load it it one thread. Whay it's not faster?...

Comment: How `send_data` was defined ?